# Cakephp 2.x generate tree nodes with Tree Behavior?

Tags: cakephp, behavior

A very simple question: is there a way to get an multidimensional array with tree nodes build with CakePHP's Tree Behavior?
I can only find [a method that output an array to use in a dropdown field](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-TreeBehavior.html#_generateTreeList)...

Comment: find(threaded)? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded

Comment: Yes indeed! But it's very strange that the book refers to the tree behavior when you use find(threaded): 
"A better way to deal with nested data is using the Tree behavior"

Comment: The wording could be improved indeed :)